# Expose <property-placeholder> properties to the Spring Environment

Tags: java, spring, properties-file, spring-environment

I have a properties file that I'm registering with Spring through XML, using the `property-placeholder` element:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties" />
```

I can access properties using `@Value` annotations, e.g.

```
@Value("${prefs.key}")
private String prefValue;
```

but I also need to access properties via the Spring Environment, e.g.

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

public String getValue(String key) {
  return env.getProperty(key);
}
```

`getValue()` here always returns `null`, even for keys defined in the properties file, because it seems that using `<property-placeholder>` does not expose properties to the Environment. Is there a way to force properties loaded this way to be accessible via the Environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Spring 3.2.x [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) and introduction [blog post](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/):

> Prior to Spring 3.1, the `context:property-placeholder` namespace
>   element registered an instance of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. It
>   will still do so if using the `spring-context-3.0.xsd` definition of the
>   namespace. That is, you can preserve registration of
>   `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` through the namespace, even if using
>   Spring 3.1; simply do not update your `xsi:schemaLocation` and continue
>   using the 3.0 XSD.

So, my guess is that your XMLs are *not* using the proper XSD version.

Comment: I'm currently using `spring-context-3.0.xsd` as the XSD -- but bizarrely, switching to the 3.1 version of the XSD causes properties to be exposed to the Environment in the way I'd expected.

Thanks!